# Efeito de div torta

Tags: html, css

Bom tenho uma div `box2-1` que tem o `width` em 100%. Quero criar uma div `box2-2` que tenha o `width` em 100%, porém que manter o background com duas cores, para ter um efeito de uma div torta. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código. O problema e que não estou conseguindo colocar a div `box2-2` com `width` em 100%.

```css
.box2-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FF895B;
}
.box2-2 {
    border-right-width: 899px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
    bottom: -60px;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box2-1">
            
        </div>
        <div class="box2-2"></div>
```

Exemplo da div que quero criar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer fazer algo como o gradiente?

Comment: Hugo, poderia por gentileza fazer um esboço de como ficaria essa div torta, pode ser no paint mesmo, só para ter uma ideia melhor de como te ajudar...

Comment: se vc colocar 605px ela fica certa aqui... mas nao vai funcionar no seu site provavelmente ...

Comment: @Marconi isso mesmo que eu estou querendo.

Comment: @HugoBorges, não precisa de duas divs para fazer um [gradiente](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)...

Comment: da pra fazer com jQuery.. pegando o width da div 1 e setando pra propriedade do div 2 no ` resize`

Comment: @Mathias quero fazer um div assim: http://i.imgur.com/AwJtGA5.png Porém com with:100%

Answer (score 3):

Essa é a idéia:
Você pega o `width` da div 2-1 e aplica à borda da div 2-2.
mesmo que o usuário redimensione a tela, você não vai perder o efeito, pois ele está linkado ao `window.resize` tb.

Não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer, mas funciona.

```js
function adjustBorder(){
  var div1Width = $('.box2-1').width();
  $('.box2-2').css('border-right-width', div1Width+ 'px');
}

window.onresize = function(event) {
  adjustBorder();
}

adjustBorder();
```

```css
.box2-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FF895B;
}
.box2-2 {
    border-right-width: 899px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
    bottom: -60px;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box2-1">
            
</div>
<div class="box2-2"></div>
```

Comment: +1  "Não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer" kkk, mas a ideia é boa!

Comment: Bom funcionou, mas não sei se dessa forma é a melhor. Acho que em CSS da para resolver. +1, se ninguém postar uma solução melhor eu marco como resolvido ok.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma que achei foi assim:

```css
.box2 {
  background-color: #FF895B;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
.box2:after {
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(1.5deg);
  transform-origin: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Box 2 -->
        <div class="box2">
            
        </div>
```

Fonte: https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms

Comment: poutz man ... mandou bem ... eu tava tentando algo com `skew` mas nao cheguei a tentar o `skew-y`... +1